# Timer job issue with accessing credentials in securestore

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs, secure-store

have 3 timer jobs accessing same secure store for credentials, two of them work fine and the third one is failing

The error I am getting is as follows. I checke credentials and they are fine.  Any ideas?

Secure Store Service did not performed the operation.: at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.Execute[T](String operationName, Boolean validateCanary, ExecuteDelegate`1 operation) at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceApplicationProxy.GetCredentials(Guid rawPartitionId, String applicationId) at Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStore.GetCredentials(String applicationId) at xxxxxxxx.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4() at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) at xxxxxxxx

The exception details are
An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '      IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The Secure Store Service application Secure Store Services is not accessible. The full exception text is: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '      IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The same works on another farm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stopped the started SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool to fix the issue